# How to multiple maps on the same page using Ionic and angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, maps, ionic-framework

I am trying to load multiple maps on the same page in my app(let's say 2 for example).

the html looks like this:

```
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:400px; height:500px" ></div>
        <div id="map_canvas1" style="width:400px; height:500px" ></div>
```

the .js file looks like this:

```
    var myOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.71, 74),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }


    var map_canvas = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
    if (map_canvas)
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, myOptions);
    var map_canvas1 = document.getElementById("map_canvas1");
    if (map_canvas1)
        var map2 = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas1, myOptions);
```

The maps appear on the page but they don't load(it's just a gray background)

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your example and it worked. The only thing I have changed is 'zoom' property which I have set to 3, because the map was zoomed in too much, maybe that was the reason why gray areas were showing for you. Try with:

```
var myOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.71, 74),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
```